# Can I have a selector as a property in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can I have a selector as a property in iOS?
Something like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SEL *mySelector;
```

Comment: It would be better to use `NSStringFromSelector` and `selectorFromString`.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer Why?

Comment: @Luda - Apple does this in a few places. See the `action` property of `UIBarButtonItem` for one example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, but not a `strong` one since it's not an object type.

Also `SEL` shouldn't be a pointer (unless you really mean it)

```
@property (nonatomic) SEL mySelector;
```

---

As a bonus, here's the actual definition of the `SEL` type, taken from `objc.h`

```
/// An opaque type that represents a method selector.
typedef struct objc_selector *SEL;
```